# Spark on Yarn: AM container size

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, cloudera

I am running Spark job on YARN I have issue with AM container size. I deploy it in the cluster mode. Upon its start, I see following line in the log.

```
INFO yarn.Client: Will allocate AM container, with 1408 MB memory including 384 MB overhead
```

Occasionaly, as job is fairly large, I get

```
INFO - ERROR yarn.Client: Application diagnostics message: Application application_1606984713739_1759 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1606984713739_1759_000002 exited with  exitCode: -104    
INFO - Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: Container [pid=386064,containerID=container_e69_1606984713739_1759_02_000001] is running 5566464B beyond the 'PHYSICAL' memory limit. Current usage: 1.5 GB of 1.5 GB physical memory used; 3.3 GB of 3.1 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.
```

How can I increase the AM size? It was my understanding that it should take memory of `spark.driver.memory`, or something close to it depending on `yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb` (I have minimum set to 1GiB and maximum to 32 GiB).

Spark configuration for a given job is as follows (and I can see this in Spark UI Environment, so it is really set):

```
(spark.submit.deployMode,cluster)
...
(spark.executor.extraJavaOptions,-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35)
(spark.executor.memory,20g)
(spark.executor.cores,5)
(spark.executor.instances,8)
(spark.driver.memoryOverhead,4g)
(spark.driver.memory,12g)
(spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors,4)
(spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors,30)
(spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled,true)
```

What is the reason I am still getting so small AM container?

Comment: how do you submit your application?

Comment: Using spark-submit: like spark-submit --class MyClass --master=yarn --deploy-mode=cluster  MyClass.jar

Comment: Hmmm... make sure you set the configs before creating a `SparkSession`, because otherwise the driver memory may appear to be "correct" in UI while in fact being the default. Container allocation message is the true indicator of what memory was really requested.

Comment: `SparkSession.builder()
      .config("spark.driver.memory","12g")
      .config("driver.memoryOverhead","4g")
      (...)
      .getOrCreate()`

I do it like this. Is there something wrong with this approach?

Comment: if before that call you try a `SparkSession.active()` and it returns you something, then a `.getOrCreate()` in your code is a simple `get` and returns an existing session with driver container already started.